# Hair rotation doesn't understand global Z

Tags: particles, hair

Why aren't these hair particles sticking up? I want them to stick up and to add a random rotation around their Z axis.

If I change the orientation axis to Global Y or Global X or Object X or Object Y then the particles will stick up but that's obviously a bug. In any case, randomizing rotation will not rotate them around the object's Z axis.

Does anyone know how to work around this bug?

[image: Blender being wrong]

Comment: This isn't an official Blender developer forum. If you want to report a bug please use Help>>Report a bug menu inside Blender.

Comment: Take the object you are using as the particle, go into edit mode, and rotate it 90 degrees, and your issue should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks @FFeller but my question was how to work around the bug. Obviously I can't wait for months for a fix to be released.

Comment: @person132 Thanks, that worked. If you add an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: It's not a bug, it just is still the case for (I think) legacy reasons that X+ is up in the world of particles.  Now as to WHY it was made that way in the first place, who knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that while while the particle system is indeed pointing the objects towards the global z, it is pointing the front of the objects (in the +y direction i believe) towards the global z. In this case, you want the object to stay standing up, so if you rotate the original mesh by 90 degrees, the correct direction will be aligned to global z in the particle system.